# How should I manage my charging cycles to extend battery life?

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, charging

I use my laptop throughout the day for various work. My usage starts sometime after breakfast and continuous into night, till about 9 pm, then breaks for dinner and continues for another hour or two. During this entire while, my laptop obviously gets discharge a couple of times. What I currently do is, I plug it in whenever the battery drops below 25% and keep it plugged till it goes back to full. This repeats in cycles. I usually encounter about 3 such cycles.

Of late, I have grown more conscious about this, and each time I plug it for charging I get worried that I am actually damaging my device instead of preserving it, given that I am constantly sitting next to the AC power supply but yet making my battery work hard throughout the day.

Is there any way I can optimize my usage, to achieve the end goal of extending the general durability and endurance of my battery device?

**TL;DR**: I frequently charge my laptop and I sit near the AC supply all day. Any way to optimize my battery life in this specific situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Batteries have a finite life, there are a lot of different aspect involved in a battery life; however the one we concern about here is "Cycle life".

> The cycle life is the number of complete charge/discharge cycles that the battery is able to support before that its capacity falls under 80% of it's original capacity. [[1]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-batterys-cycle-life)

In an other words:

> In general, number of cycles for a rechargeable battery indicates how many times it can undergo the process of complete charging and discharging until failure or it starting to lose capacity [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_cycle)

What you are doing is repeating this cycle over and over and thus decreasing your battery's life.

Remember that you shouldn't let your battery to be charged to 100% of its capacity over and over and also reach to the 0%.

So the best thing to do is controlling the charging process.

Based on your laptop there might be different tools available to you. For example if you have a "Lenovo ThinkPad" you can use `tlp` to  easily manage this process.

It got a bunch of configuration items which makes us able to control battery's charge thresholds:

```
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=75
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=80
```

> Charging starts upon connecting AC power, but only if the remaining capacity is below the value of START_CHARGE_TRESH (start threshold). Charging stops when reaching the STOP_CHARGE_TRESH (stop threshold) value. If, however when you connect the AC adapter, charge is above the start threshold, then it will not charge. [[3]](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#chargethresholds)

So we can keep our AC plugged-in all the time while we are controlling the charge process. Something between 60% to 65% while you always using AC is a safe number to go with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do use a thinkpad so I'll try that out. However, you mentioned that battery life reduced with each charging dischargimg cycle. By keeping it within 60-70%, we have to charge/discharge it several times, and wouldn't that itself damage the battery, or am I understanding the functioning of Li ion batteries wrong?

Comment: I meant keeping it between those numbers with a intelligent program like `tlp` not by charging and discharging it ourself. e.g I let my battery charge drop to 60٪ and let's say my thresholds has been set between 45 and 65, then I connect my AC adapter; Now my laptop charges stays at 60% as long as AC adapter is connected and laptop intelligently knows that it shouldn't charge the battery cause it's above the threshold, thus  it's like charging the battery to 60% and removing it from laptop.

Comment: And what if the notebook is not a Thinkpad and doesn't support charging thresholds and also doesn't have a removable battery?

Comment: In that particular situation I don't have any idea, however there should be a logic behind that design which protects the battery's life I guess.

Comment: @Ravexina [Nope](http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/551/854/06f.jpg), more like "your battery's toast? Pay $$$ for a new one!"

Comment: @muru so that's the logic behind it :D

Comment: I get this: `Error: ThinkPad extended battery functions not available.` even though I obviously own a ThinkPad.

Comment: Depends  on your Thinkpad you should install other packages to enable these functionalities, I guess it was `tp-smapi-dkms` and `acpi-call-dkms` for me.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to avoid worrying about your battery: make sure your laptop is (at least relatively) stationary and remove its battery while keeping it always plugged in. In that case, fill the batter to 100% and store it somewhere without light and with temps of around 20-25 degrees.

This should work wonders, unless you're a businessman/ presenter and have to move your laptop from place to place and do presentation/ etc.